# Replace checkbox select with bolding caption

Tags: html, checkbox

I'm not sure if I got the title right. But my point is:

I want to replace standard checkox, eg:

```
Select <input type="checkbox" name="sel" />
```

with something witch will allow me to click on text (like 'select' in above code) and by clicking it I would select 'sel' property and make this text bold. Clicking it again would deselect it and unbold text.
A don't want to checkox to be shown.

Ideas? I thought of javascript but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the label-node around.

```
<label>
  Select 
  <input type="checkbox" hidden="true"
    onclick="parentNode.style.fontWeight=checked?'bold':'';" />
</label>
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks! So I can now use "hidden" property in input tag and selection works! But how can I bold text, so I know when it's selected? Onclick event somehow?

Comment: Could You be more specific?

Comment: iv added onclick to my answer on top

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css to define text in chrome.

```
<style> 
input:before{content:attr(myTextAnno)}
input:checked{font-weight:bold;}
</style>
<input type="checkbox" myTextAnno="Select">
```

You can use the css to define text in all browsers.

```
<style> 
input:before{content:'Select'}
input:checked{font-weight:bold;}
</style>
<input type="checkbox">
```

Comment: But this way every checkbox would be captioned "Select". Chrome solution doesn't work for me (it should work on all browsers anyway).